# How to create a list of lists with unequal number of elements in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to create list of the following type:

[ [1,2,3], [5,6] , [1,2,4,6,7,89,9,74,4]]

But whenever I do, matlab automatically concatenates the list. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called cell array, you can create one by doing:

```
A = {[1,2,3], [5,6], [1,2,4,6,7,89,9,74,4]};
```

To access cell elements you have to use the `{}` operator. As @TroyHaskin said, you can find a most complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766523/how-to-store-this-structure-list-of-lists-of-integers-in-matlab)